# Learning Differential Geometry through General Relativity

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, book-recommendation, general-relativity

I was wondering whether it is possible to get a fairly good understanding of the subject of differential geometry through learning General Relativity (eg from Woodhouse's book)?

Ie the sort of understanding where you know and can use the main results but dont have to go through all the depths of rigor (eg calculus vs analysis).

Comment: Maybe you could check this book, See the preface on Google Books: https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Spacetime-Introduction-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986413/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1534196036&sr=8-1&keywords=the+geometry+of+spacetime

Comment: Sorry but thats not the tack I would like to take as I dont think I will get a good understanding of GR nor much DG

Comment: From a physics textbook? No. However something like "Semi-Riemannian Geometry" by Barret O'Neill would probably be a could pick to learn differential geometry and general relativity at the same time.

Comment: @Jake how do physics textbooks approach the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible. However, in the long term, it is beneficial to study differential and Riemannian geometry. That being said these notes (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/lecturenotes_2012.pdf) are an excellent start down the right path. They are written by Prof. Harvey Reall at DAMTP, Cambridge for the graduate mathematics course in GR. They explain all the necessary bits of differential geometry to gain a good grasp on GR from a mathematical standpoint.

As a previous commenter noted, Barrett O'Neill's Semi-Riemannian Geometry is an excellent text. I would also recommend Tu's Introduction to Manifolds.

You could also consult one of the following: Wald's General Relativity (a classic and has a fair amount of geometry in the appendices), Hawking and Ellis Large Scale Structure of Spacetime (the introductory chapter is differential geometry for GR).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you say Tu's Introduction to Manifolds compares to Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds?

Comment: @Permian Sorry for the slow reply. Lee is brilliant but dense! If time allows, sure Lee is a very good option but if you're short on time Tu will get you up to speed fast. I see Lee as a reference text, not as something to read cover to cover.

Answer (score 1):

Books on general relativity tend to be choc-a-bloc with index notation and it can get a bit confusing.

My advice is first read some notes on the geometry of curves and surfaces to get the general ideas about geometry and then go for a differential geometry book.

Then once you go to general relativity, you'll not only have a firm grip of geometry, you can understand the physics better.

Comment: Whats the difference between geometry of curves and differential geometry?

Comment: It's the dimension of the manifold involved. Curves of one dimensional manifolds, surfaces are two dimensional manifolds but the dimension of the manifolds in general relativity are four dimensional.

The advantage of doing curves and surfaces is that you can get an intuitive feel for what curvature actually is. Do this and you'll be able to get into GR much more easily.